# LiveReload over HTTPS on node JS will not work

Tags: node.js, https, livereload

It had been working perfectly until I had to change to https.
Here is my configuration for livereload:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const livereload = require('livereload')
const connectLiveReload = require('connect-livereload')


const liveReloadServer = livereload.createServer();
liveReloadServer.watch(publicDirectory)
liveReloadServer.server.once("connection",()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        liveReloadServer.refresh("/");
    }, 200);
})

app.use(connectLiveReload());
```

The error it started displaying is:

[image]

And of course, it's not picking up on changes and reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the npm page of the package livereload [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload)

> **Server API**
>
> The createServer() method accepts two arguments.
>
> The first are some configuration options, passed as a JavaScript
> object:
>
> - https is an optional object of options to be passed to
>   https.createServer (if not provided, http.createServer is used
>   instead)

You can check the NodeJS document about https.createServer [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)

From that, I think the configuration of liveReloadServer will be something like this, you use your SSL certificate and key :

```
const liveReloadServer = livereload.createServer({
    https : {
        key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
    }
});
```

Comment: Could have sworn I had tried this. Funny that it works on chrome but not on Brave browser, I get the "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error.

Comment: Nvm, restarted the Brave Browser and it's working now